# Neovim lspconfig plugin: attempt to call field 'nvim_multiline_command` (a nil value)

Tags: neovim, nvim-lspconfig

Recently I'm getting this error when opening a file for which I have language server installed:

*(this is in neovim :messages)*

```
Error detected while processing BufEnter Autocommands for "<buffer=403>":
E5108: Error executing lua [string ":lua"]:47: attempt to call field 'nvim_multiline_command' (a nil value)
```

So I went searching for `nvim_multiline_command` in my init.vim and surely enough I found this:

```lua
136   -- Set autocommands conditional on server_capabilities
  1   if client.resolved_capabilities.document_highlight then
  2     require('lspconfig').util.nvim_multiline_command [[
  3       :hi LspReferenceRead cterm=bold ctermbg=red guibg=LightYellow
  4       :hi LspReferenceText cterm=bold ctermbg=red guibg=LightYellow
  5       :hi LspReferenceWrite cterm=bold ctermbg=red guibg=LightYellow
  6       augroup lsp_document_highlight
  7         autocmd!
  8         autocmd CursorHold <buffer> lua vim.lsp.buf.document_highlight()
  9         autocmd CursorMoved <buffer> lua vim.lsp.buf.clear_references()
  10       augroup END
  11     ]]                                                                                                                                                                                                      12   end                                                                                                                                                                                                       13 end
```

(yes I copied from the terminal because my clipboard stopped working, don't show this to emacs users)

I clearly remember copying this from the official readme. Not sure why this stopped working.

Answer (score 3):

[Using util_nvim_multiline_command seems to have been deprecated](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/commit/6076721c2cbe17b67d8cedc4f0b5694c35bca16f#diff-b335630551682c19a781afebcf4d07bf978fb1f8ac04c6bf87428ed5106870f5) (Link to github commit)

I recommend going to [the most recent nvim-lspconfig readme](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/README.md#keybindings-and-completion), and replacing the old version of the `--Set autocommands conditional on server_capabilities` section with the new one.

Comment: Yeah, the doc is changing rapidly, not very stable yet.